# Create RTSP stream from OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, kivy, rtsp

I'm processing an input which takes a variable amount of time per frame. The goal is to treat these images which are loaded as numpy arrays (OpenCV processing) as a video and send it into another Python application.

I have not been successful finding or implementing any good solution. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you done any effort and searches? also please share your code, if you have.

Answer (score 0):

So to stream an OpenCV image use the imagezmq package and create a client/server. This can be used to take in an input image which arrives at random times. Essentially it is always sending an image and just sends the most recently updated image.

This streams via TCP where the output can then be displayed in the application.

The below should be for demonstration purposes launched in seperate kernels on the same device (imagezmq.ImageSender() defaults to 127.0.0.1).

Client:

```
import socket
import imagezmq
import threading

class Streamer():

    '''
    Create a TCP stream
    '''

    def __init__(self):

        self.sender = imagezmq.ImageSender()

        self.deviceName = socket.gethostname()

        # launch the streamer thread
        threading.Thread(target=self.sendImage, name = "ImageStreamer").start()

        # initialise the image as empty
        self.img = None

        # set to run
        self.run = True
        

    def sendImage(self):

        ''''
        Take the objects image and send it
        '''

        while self.run:
            try:
                if self.img is not None:
                    self.sender.send_image(self.deviceName, self.img)

                else:
                    time.sleep(0.1)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

        print("---- Stream finished ----")

stream = Streamer()
while True:

    '''
    Processing and extraction of the image at whatever interval.
    Should send a numpy array representing the image. 
    '''

    stream.img = image
```

Server:

```
import imagezmq
import cv2

imageHub = imagezmq.ImageHub()

lastActive = {}

while True:
    # receive the device name and decoded image
    (name, frame) = imageHub.recv_image()

    # update the frame at ~50fps
    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame.astype(np.uint8))
    cv2.waitKey(20) 

    # send back confirmation message
    imageHub.send_reply(b'OK')

    if name not in lastActive.keys():
        print("[INFO] receiving data from {}...".format(rpiName))
    lastActive[name] = time.time()
```

Comment: gives ways to transport images over the network, but doesn't answer the main question of producing RTSP streams though..

Comment: Yes that is fair. This code solved the problem of sending variable frame rate video over a network. I was trying to send it via RTSP because that was the protocol Kivy takes but this solved the crux of the problem. RTSP was in this case a solution looking for a problem. I have updated the question to reflect what the solution was solving. Thanks.